# How to use a 3x3 homography matrix in OpenGL ES shaders?

Tags: opengl-es, computer-vision, textures, shader, homography

I have a 3x3 homography matrix that works correctly with OpenCV's `warpPerspective`, but I need to do the warping on GPU for performance reasons. What is the best approach? I tried multiplying in the vertex shader to get the texture coordinates and then render a quad, but I get strange distortions. I'm not sure if it's the interpolation not working as I expect. Attaching output for comparison (it involves two different, but close enough shots).

Absolute difference of warp and other image from GPU:

[image]

Composite of warp and other image in OpenCV:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Following are my shaders: the task is image rectification (making epilines become scanlines) + absolute difference.

```
// Vertex Shader

static const char* warpVS = STRINGIFY
(
 uniform highp mat3 homography1;
 uniform highp mat3 homography2;
 uniform highp int width;
 uniform highp int height;
 attribute highp vec2 position;
 varying highp vec2 refTexCoords;
 varying highp vec2 curTexCoords;

 highp vec2 convertToTexture(highp vec3 pixelCoords) {
   pixelCoords /= pixelCoords.z;  // need to project
   pixelCoords /= vec3(float(width), float(height), 1.0);
   pixelCoords.y = 1.0 - pixelCoords.y;  // origin is in bottom left corner for textures
   return pixelCoords.xy;
 }

 void main(void)
 {
   gl_Position = vec4(position / vec2(float(width) / 2.0, float(height) / 2.0) - vec2(1.0), 0.0, 1.0);
   gl_Position.y = -gl_Position.y;
   highp vec3 initialCoords = vec3(position, 1.0);
   refTexCoords = convertToTexture(homography1 * initialCoords);
   curTexCoords = convertToTexture(homography2 * initialCoords);
 }

 );

// Fragment Shader

static const char* warpFS = STRINGIFY
(
 varying highp vec2 refTexCoords;
 varying highp vec2 curTexCoords;
 uniform mediump sampler2D refTex;
 uniform mediump sampler2D curTex;
 uniform mediump sampler2D maskTex;

 void main(void)
 {
   if (texture2D(maskTex, refTexCoords).r == 0.0) {
     discard;
   }

   if (any(bvec4(curTexCoords[0] < 0.0, curTexCoords[1] < 0.0, curTexCoords[0] > 1.0, curTexCoords[1] > 1.0))) {
     discard;
   }

   mediump vec4 referenceColor = texture2D(refTex, refTexCoords);
   mediump vec4 currentColor = texture2D(curTex, curTexCoords);

   gl_FragColor = vec4(abs(referenceColor.r - currentColor.r), 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 }

 );
```

Comment: Can you describe what exclty you are doing, OpenGL-wise, "I tried multiplying in the vertex shader to get the texture coordinates and then render a quad" is a bit vague to me. What exactly did you do with the vertex and texture cooddinates? The effect you want to achieve can be achieved with OpenGL, and there are many different possible approaches. It is also hard to judge what exactly did go wrong from this picture alone. Most likely, you didn't get the correct texture transformation with the non-affine projective transform right.

Comment: @derhass I added the shader code and the task I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @aledalgrande Hi! Were you able to do the warpPerspective part of your app in OpenGL ? Is your code public? If not, could you give me some exact pointers on how to go about it? I'm having similar problems. warpPerspective is taking ~200ms on multiple phones, when I'm overlay small video frames on current camera preview frame, in place of a detected object. Basic AR.

Comment: @bad_keypoints I did not do it in OpenGL in the end, but in [Metal](https://github.com/aledalgrande/warpExample). You can take a look and see how you can translate into OpenGL, it shouldn't be much different. Beware I had some numerical problems due to Metal bugs, so I had to write workarounds (see commits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to do the projection per pixel. Make refTexCoords and curTexCoords at least vec3, then do the /z in the pixel shader before texture lookup. Even better use the textureProj GLSL instruction.

You want to do everything that is linear in the vertex shader, but things like projection need to be done in the fragment shader per pixel.

This link might help with some background: http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2012/05/26/quadrilateral-interpolation-part-1/

Comment: But how can I use `texture2Dproj` if the coordinates are in the range 0,0 -> 640,480 after the multiplication `homography2 * initialCoords`?

Comment: You transform (u,v,q) coordinates by your 3x3 matrix yielding a 3 element vector (u',v',q'). q is what you use for projection. The 3x3 matrix should include computing q. See the linked article for what values of q make sense.

Comment: In the end I just had to use a different homography and do the projective divide in the pixel shader, like you said.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the bounty. I only answer SO when it's late :). So for the sake of other people reading this, can you explain more what you had to do? I was thrown off quite a bit by the word "homography". In rendering it's called a projection matrix. It's job is to get the right q (or z) coordinate for the projective divide that you have to do per pixel. In 3d that is just z, depth etc. linearly scaled. But in a pure 2d case you have to compute that z value. And it is not linear. You have to use information over your topology (like cross the edges) to compute it. That's what my link was for.